# How to copy specific text from one file to another using python?

Tags: python, facebook, scripting

I am writing a python script to copy only the facebook group_id's from file A to file B.
The code I am using here is

```
searchquery = 'group_id='
with open('h1.txt') as f1:
    with open('h2.txt', 'a') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if searchquery in line:
                f2.write(line)`
```

When I run this script,it runs successfully and the h2.txt file is created as the copy of h1.txt. Can anyone guide me as to what is going wrong?

Also is there any efficient method of extracting the only the facebook group names and links other than what I am doing then please do share. Thanks

My h1.txt file is [here](http://pastebin.com/wiR5fss1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `data` from `h1.txt` is on a single line so you end up writing all the data to `h2.txt` as your `if searchquery in line`  is True so you write the line which happens to be the only line in `h1.txt` to `h2.txt`, if you just want the `group_id =..` use a regex:

```
with open("h1.txt") as f:
    import  re
    dat = f.read()
    print(re.findall("group_id=\d+", data))
```

Output:

```
['group_id=132946160231517', 'group_id=132946160231517', 'group_id=193252980718262', 'group_id=193252980718262', 'group_id=399162576788186', 'group_id=399162576788186']
```

If you just want the ids:

```
 dat = f.read()
 print(re.findall("group_id=(\d+)",data))

 ['132946160231517', '132946160231517', '193252980718262', '193252980718262', '399162576788186', '399162576788186']
```

If you want the names:

```
 re.findall('"name":"(.*?)"',data)
```

Comment: So is there any solution you can suggest? Or any other method then please do share.

Comment: You can try find a common delimiter to split on but I imagine you can extract  the data you need as json or in some usable format, how did you  get the data?

Comment: There is a facebook api to do this kind of thing programmatically but you could just use a regex to extract what you want, what exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: Can you help me in displaying the name along with the group_id using reqex as I am new to it. My aim is to display the name and group_id

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> with open('h1.txt') as f:
...     re.findall(r'group_id=[0-9]+', f.read())
...
['group_id=132946160231517', 'group_id=132946160231517', 'group_id=193252980718262', 'group_id=193252980718262', 'group_id=399162576788186', 'group_id=399162576788186']
```

Comment: Can you help me in displaying the name along with the group_id using regex and excluding the duplicated group_id if possible. My aim is to display the name and group_id

Comment: If you want to get multiple fields, you better convert the data to `json` and use `key`s, since this is dictionary data which don't have any particular order.